# ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined in Java, SQL Developer works

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I created a select in Oracle SQL Developer

```
select PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.PRZYJECIEID as Numer_przyjęcia, 
       PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.PACJENTID as ID_pacjęta, 
       PACJENT.PACJENTIMIE as Imię,
       PACJENT.PACJENTNAZWISKO as Nazwisko,
       PACJENT.PESEL as PESEL, 
       PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.ROZPOZNANIE AS DIAGNOZA,
       PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.NAZWAODDZIALU as ODDZIAŁ, 
       PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.DATAPRZ as DATA_PRZYJĘCIA, 
       LEKARZ.LEKARZIMIE as Imię_lekarza, 
       LEKARZ.LEKARZNAZWISKO as Nazwisko_lekarza, 
       PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.UWAGI 
  from SZPITAL_DB.PACJENT, SZPITAL_DB.LEKARZ, SZPITAL_DB.PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL 
 where PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.PACJENTID = PACJENT.PACJENTID 
   and PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.LEKARZID = LEKARZ.LEKARZID
```

When i run It in SQL Developer works very good:
[image]

but when i put it into Java i got an error:

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Java code:

```
 private void Get_Data(){
   String sql="select PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.PRZYJECIEID as Numer_przyjęcia, PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.PACJENTID as ID_pacjęta, PACJENT.PACJENTIMIE as Imię,PACJENT.PACJENTNAZWISKO as Nazwisko,PACJENT.PESEL as PESEL, PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.ROZPOZNANIE AS DIAGNOZA,PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.NAZWAODDZIALU as ODDZIAŁ,PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.DATAPRZ as DATA_PRZYJĘCIA, LEKARZ.LEKARZIMIE as Imię_lekarza, LEKARZ.LEKARZNAZWISKO as Nazwisko_lekarza, PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.UWAGI from SZPITAL_DB.PACJENT,SZPITAL_DB.LEKARZ, SZPITAL_DB.PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL where PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.PACJENTID = PACJENT.PACJENTID and PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL.LEKARZID = LEKARZ.LEKARZID";
   try{         pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
      rs= pst.executeQuery();
     jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
     }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
```

Comment: The edit is useful but now it's more difficult to check that the 2 requests are the same, so I'll put this here: **I verified, they were exactly the same before**, this is not a trivial typo. And now with the edited formatting we can see you have prefixed every reference, so there should be no ambiguity...

Comment: Since you have explicitly defined your tables in each column reference, you shouldn't be getting this error. So that tells me that you either have a typo somewhere or you have discovered an error in the Java library you are using. I would recommend trying to intercept the call that is ultimately being passed to the database. You are probably not actually sending the same script through Java that you are through SQL Developer.

Comment: Make your sql statement as small as possible, we need/want not the full statement to analyze your problem! And format it in a way that makes it easy to read/compare/analyze.

Comment: Try dropping one column after another from the select, until it succeeds.  Then at least you'll know which column is giving the problem.

Comment: What character set is Java (or your OS) using? My guess, FWIW, is that the two aliases that start with `Imi` are being confused beyond that because of the multibyte characters. Which could be a JDBC driver/compatibility issue too, perhaps. Is it the same JDK and driver for both? Can you try changing one of those aliases - before the fourth char - and see if it makes any difference? (I assume you're really sure it is *this* query that is erroring?)

Comment: I believe @AlexPoole has got this right.  However, if there's an incompatibility between your JDBC driver and your database, as far as how multibyte characters are transmitted, then just changing the column aliases isn't going to be enough of a fix.  You'll need to research what international character settings are available in both the database and the driver, and make sure they're compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess from the code you posted, you appear to have defined

```
SZPITAL_DB.PACJENT, 
SZPITAL_DB.LEKARZ, 
SZPITAL_DB.PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL
```

in the FROM statement but you appear to refer to it using the table names for e.g.`PRZYJECIE_NA_ODDZIAL` without the Database name for e.g. `SZPITAL_DB.` in the SELECT statement.  The same applies for `PACJENTID`and `LEKARZID`.

As mentioned by @DanK, perhaps you have a spelling mistake in your table names?

Comment: You do not need to repeat the schema in the select list if you have fully qualified them in the `FROM` clause - and that would not result in a **column** ambiguously defined